# openerp-server: error: no such option: -p

Tags: docker, odoo

I tried to run Odoo v8 docker.

If I add the container id, it runs but does not provide port number. If I enter the port number as follows:

> docker run d69ffe949669 -p 127.0.0.1:8069:8069 --name odoo --link
>   db:db -t odoo

if says:

> openerp-server: error: no such option: -p

if I run the entire command without the container id, it runs Odoo v9

Please help me to start Odoo v8

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of docker run command is:

> $ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

So you have 2 options here (they are the same but one uses the image name and tag and the other uses the image id):

`docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo:8`

or

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t d69ffe949669
```

PS: if you do not specify version tag it uses latest image which is version 9.